# Laravel: Consultation with multiple with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
$items = RequestItems::where('requests.user_id', '=', $user->id)
      ->orderBy('requests.id', 'desc')
      ->with(['item', 'image', 'gratitude', 'item.user', 'gratitude.gratitude_image'])
      ->paginate(10);
```

From which I get this:

[image]

I try to access from Blade to the fields in gratitude_image in a foreach but it doesn't give me:

```
{{$item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0]}}
```

But it doesn't bring me the information. Please help…

Comment: What is `$item`? Are you looping over `$items` like `@foreach($items as $item)`? Also, `'gratitude'` in your `with` is unnecessary, `'gratitude.gratitude_image'` will include `gratitude`. Lastly, why is `gratitiude_image` a Collection? Your naming (singular) suggests it should be a single record, `gratitude_images` (plural) would suggest a Collection.

Comment: Exactly, $item is from the @foreach path as you indicate. gratitiude_image is a table in my database associated with the gratitude table by its id. That is, the gratitude_image table contains images related to the gratitude table ...

Comment: Ok, so then it _should_ work, unless the gratitude of the `$item` you're iterating on doesn't have an image. In a loop, there's a chance that `$item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0]` is not defined. If you did `$item->gratitude->gratitude_image->first()` it _shouldn't_ thrown an error, or `{{ $item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0] ?? null }}`. Maybe add your relationships to the question as well; it seems a little confusing.

Comment: The relationship is like this: The "gratitude" table is related one to many through its "id" with the "gratitude_image" table through its "gratitude_id" field ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `with`. There are basically two types of loading,`lazy loading`, `eager loading`. And one more you can add `lazy eager loading`.

So what should you do now with these terms?. Just define the required relations in the respective model classes and then in the blade file you can simply use `lazy loading` and you don't need to use `with`.

Example: `{{ $item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0]->id ?? 'Not Found' }}`

Here, this is a conditional statement. If there exists an `id` then it will be printed else `Not Found` will be printed. And instead of directly calling the `0th index`, you can also use `foreach` loop to iterate through all of your entries.